# jQGrid reload not working once table becomes empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am having an issue with jqGrid relaod.

So here is what I have.

when my page load I build a table

```
  $("#systemPropList").jqGrid(
        {
          url : '${servletPath}/systemProperties.data',
          colNames:['Key Name','Key Value','Description','System Name','Work'],
          colModel : [
                {name:'propertyKey',index:'propertyKey', width:155, align:'center'},
                {name:'propertyValue',index:'propertyValue', width:100, align:'center'},
                {name:'propertyDescription',index:'propertyDescription'},
                {name:'propertySystemName',index:'propertySystemName', width:100, align:'center'},
                {name:'propertyId', sortable:false, width:60, align:'center', formatter:workButtons }
          ],
          sortname: 'propertyKey',
          sortorder: "desc"
        })
```

I have a select box on the top to reload this table based on the value selected from dropbox and I have bind the reload to the onChange.

```
 $("select[name=systemName]").change(function(obj){
            gridReload();
 });

    function gridReload(){
     $("#systemPropList").setGridParam({"page": 1});
     $("#systemPropList").jqGrid("setGridParam",{postData:{propertySystemName :     $("#systemName option:selected").val()}}).trigger("reloadGrid");
    }
```

This works fine till I select an option for which the data is available .But once I select an option that does not have any data, the table becomes empty and after the table remains empty even if I change the selection.

I checked through the firebug there is not JS error and the reload is making the correct call to server and server is returning the data.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Why do you have two setGridParam call? Make that into one and see if that solves the issue. Move `{"page":1}` into the second line

Answer (score 2):

First of all I think you should better use `postData` with `propertySystemName` defined as function:

```
postData: {
    propertySystemName: function () {
        return $("#systemName option:selected").val();
    }
}
```

(see the answer for more details). After that you will don't need to reset `propertySystemName` inside of `change` (or inside of `gridReload`).

What you can try to do is the following

```
function gridReload() {
    $("#systemPropList").jqGrid("setGridParam", {lastpage: 1})
        .trigger("reloadGrid", [page: 1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured out the issue. It was because some engineer has overridden the jqGrid to display custom messages in case of error and no data and while doing that they removed the jqGrid first row and replaced it with DIV of the error message. So I just replaced that with appending the same DIV in another TR rather than replacing the first row.